# How to run bootinfoscript from the GParted liveCD?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-7, gparted, live-cd

How to run `bootinfoscript` from the **GParted live CD**? Windows 7 on internal hard drive, and Linux on an external USB SSD drive (Linux not loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to boot from a live DVD, set up an internet connection, open a terminal and download the script. After downloading the script into a ~/Downloads directory you can use...

```
sudo ~/Downloads/bootinfoscript
```

This will create a RESULTS.txt in the same directory holding all the information the script collected.

[Source bootscript help](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) (link has more information).

Comment: I'm booting from GParted live CD, downloaded boot_info_script.sh which has been saved in `/home/user` directory. There is no Desktop and Downloads directories. I tried run command from Terminal `sudo bash ~/home/user/boot_info_script.sh` but it not work.

Comment: What is the ~ in this command? And what is "user"? Why "bash"? Any error notice?

Comment: I had to change location to current directory where script was saved to. It works now.. `sudo ./bootinfoscript`